# Composer package dependencies are not loading with main package

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a composer package that in turn should load a couple of dependencies, but is not.

My top level (testing project) composer,json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
    "jrmadsen67/mahana-generator-scaffolding": "dev-master@dev"
},
```

From `jrmadsen67/mahana-generator-scaffolding` (full file here: https://github.com/jrmadsen67/MahanaGeneratorScaffolding/blob/master/composer.json) - (I've tried with "minimum-stability": "dev" but that did not make any difference)

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "jrmadsen67/mahana-laravel5-generators": "dev-master",
    "laracasts/generators": "dev"
},
```

`jrmadsen67/mahana-laravel5-generators` can be found here: https://github.com/jrmadsen67/mahana-laravel5-generators

`laracasts/generators` is a several years old project. Both the Generators dependent packages load fine individually; the issue is something in how I am trying to call them from the parent composer.json, I'm sure.

TIA!

Comment: "The requested package laracasts/generators dev exists as laracasts/generators[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned your `jrmadsen67/mahana-generator-scaffolding` repo, did `composer install`and got the following error:

> The requested package laracasts/generators dev exists as laracasts/generators[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.

So, I forked your repo, changed the `laracasts/generators` constraint to "dev-master" instead. Then, I tested my fork and it seemed to install fine.

I made [PR](https://github.com/jrmadsen67/MahanaGeneratorScaffolding/pull/8), but it's a simple fix you can  make in about 2 seconds if this helps out your issue.